# How to define a method which monitors content change on a page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, controller, notifications, actionmailer

I've setup Action Mailer in my RoR app, and I would like it to send an email to the user when the content of their "MatchCenter" page changes.

The MatchCenter displays items using eBay's API, based on criteria that a user provides through microposts. This means the results are constantly changing due to an outside source, eBay, not any action on the part of the user.

I was thinking of creating a MatchCenter controller and defining a method within it that monitors for changes to the MatchCenter page. I would then have it call `UserMailer.matchcenter_notification(@user).deliver` if a change occurs.

The part I'm having trouble figuring out is what to put in the MatchCenter controller method that will detect page changes due to an outside source. Also, if there is a better way to do this, I'd love to hear it. All associated code is below. Thanks!

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: [:index, :destroy]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])    
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the MatchCenter Alpha Test!"    
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

  end


  def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted."
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end

  end


  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

microposts_controller.rb:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def new 
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
  end

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Sweet! The item has been added to your watch list, and we'll notify you whenever matches are found."
      redirect_to buy_path
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    redirect_to buy_path
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:keyword, :min, :max, :condition)
    end

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If `MatchCenter` is a model which gets modified when changes are detected in Ebay, then you could easily implement this using an observer.

If this is a pre-rails-4 app, then Observers are baked in. With rails 4 they've been [moved into a plugin](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers).

Create your observer:

```
rails g observer MatchCenter
```

Then in the newly created observer file, define what it is observing and what to do with it:

```
class MatchCenterObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe MatchCenter

  def notify_users(match_center)
    #
    # Do any required notifications etc here
    #
  end
  alias_method :after_create, :notify_users
  alias_method :after_update, :notify_users
  alias_method :after_destroy, :notify_users
end
```